# И снова сокеты в java android

Tags: java, android, сокет

Я хотел бы спросить про сокеты в Android. Я перерыл половину интернета и не нашел того, что мне нужно.

Задача написать клиент под Android на Java, который бы отправлял и получал сообщения. Когда писал на компьютер, все было чудесно, тут же столкнулся с проблемой многопоточности (нельзя вызывать сетевые задачи из главного потока). Я более менее разобрался, заставил отправлять сообщения на сервер, но никак не получается сделать, чтобы TextView сам принимал и обновлял историю диалога.

Вот код клиента, сервер даже переписал как простой эхо сервер, отсылает обратно то, что отправил клиент. Ниже код клиента, помогите с реализацией приема сообщений от сервера.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Socket socket;
    private Button SendBut;
    private EditText editText;
    private TextView textView;
    private PrintWriter os;
    private BufferedReader is;
    networking net;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SendBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SendBut);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtFrSrv);
        net = new networking();
        net.execute();
    }

    public void onClck(View view) {
        String txt = null;
        txt = editText.getText().toString();
        os.println(txt);
    }


    public class networking extends AsyncTask < String, Void, Void > {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String...params) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4444);
                os = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Пытался изобразить что то похожее на это, но с нулевым значение запустить не получается...

```
public class getMsg extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try {
            is=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            final String finc;
            finc=is.readLine();
            while (!finc.equals("break")){
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText(finc);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void GetMsg(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket=new Socket(Host,4444);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (true){
                String msg = null;
                try {
                    msg=is.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (msg==null){
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    displayMsg(msg);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void displayMsg(String msg){
    final String msg1 = msg;
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           appendTextAndScroll(msg1);
        }
    });
}
```

Всем большое спасибо за помощь, я немного переделал клиент и решил данную проблему вот таким кодом, надеюсь кому-нибудь это будет полезно. Метод GetMsg вызываю в onCreate().

Comment: На самом деле Вы ничего не изменили, Вы написали больше кода, т.к. изначально неправильно использовали AsyncTask, пытаясь постить изменения в UI поток из метода doInBackground.
AsyncTask в Android - призван заменить прямую работу с Thread, что облегчает работу с потоками.

Comment: Ну я не согласен, я полностью убрал AsyncTask и сделал все просто в отдельных потоках, возможно вы и правы, я не достаточно хорошо разобрался в AsyncTask и поэтому пытался реализовать данную задачу через него.

Comment: [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) - работает на Thread и Runnable, но скрывает их и делает работу с потоками удобнее. Вы, просто, написали свой AsyncTask, поэтому на самом деле ничего, фактически, в алгоритме не поменяли. Не разобравшись с AsyncTask, вы создали свой "велосипед". В Android для задач с бэкграунд задачами рекомендуется использовать именно AsyncTask.

Comment: Так вы же сами говорили, что AsyncTask не лучший вариант работы с сетью, таким образом я даже исходя из ваших же слов принял абсолютно верное решение

Comment: Да, AsyncTask - не лучшее решение для работы с сетью, но в данном случае я комментирую ваш код. Еще раз повторю, что вы ничего не изменили, вы, просто написали больше кода. И ваш вариант не лучше (а возможно и хуже, т.к. это "велосипед", который не учитывает всех особенностей работы с потоками) чем AsyncTask. В Android при работе с долгими бэкграунд задачами (в частности с сетью) рекомендуется использовать сервисы. [Google I/O 2010 Пример на основе REST](https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-developing-RESTful-android-apps.pdf)

Comment: Тогда предложите лучший вариант?Я полностью убрал из кода AsyncTask и вместо него начал использовать обычные потоки. Я не понимаю, что вас не устраивает? Этот "велосипед" вполне не плохо себя зарекомендовал)

Comment: @mit, вы еще скажите, что для всех сетевых запросов нужно сервис создавать. Я сразу на ios пересяду

Answer (score 6):

Use retrofit Luke!

Retrofit+rxJava+retrolambda

Допустим ответ от сервера такой

```
{"text":"текст сообщения"}
```

Как обрабатываем

```
public class Message{
 @SerializedName("text") public String message;
}

public interface RequestApi {
    String BASE_URL = "http://server/";
    RequestApi api = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RequestApi.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
                .build()
                .create(RequestApi.class);
    @GET("?method=getMsg")
    Observable<Message> getMessage();
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SendBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SendBut);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtFrSrv);
        RequestApi.api.getMessage().subscribe(m->textView.setText(m.message));
    }
}
```

Comment: Это лучший вариант, но RxJava и Retrofit не спасет от проблем со сменой конфигурации. Нужно сделать колбэк или использовать EventBus для обработки запросов. Ну, или привязывать RxJava к жизненному циклу активити.

Answer (score 4):

Вот решение вашей задачи

```
private class Networking extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4444);
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                writer.write(params[0]);
                writer.flush();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                return result.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    }
```

И вызывать `AsyncTask` необходимо из метода `onClick()`

```
new Networking().execute(text);
```

Comment: AsyncTask не лучший вариант для работы с сетью. Если в момент работы с сетью пользователь изменит конфигурацию, к примеру, перевернет смартфон (изменит ориентацию экрана), то активити будет пересоздана и в методе onPostExecute, при попытке сделать textView.setText(s), Вы получите NPE в UI потоке, что уронит все приложение.

Comment: полностью с вами согласен. Но так как автор вопроса попытался решить задачу именно с помощью этого класса, я ему подсказал, как это сделать

Comment: @mit, `AsyncTask` хороший выбор, привыкли просто все к библиотекам и не знают уже какой минус очередной придумать.

Answer (score 1):

А почему ты хочешь, чтобы это делал `TextView`? Как ты себе это представляешь? `TextView` - это всего лишь объект лейаута.

Если ты создаешь какой-то `writer`,

```
os = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
```

то очевидно ты хочешь чтобы он тебе писал в исходящий поток- `getOutputStream()`. Если тебе нужно получать информацию, то скорее всего тебе нужен `reader`, который тебе ее читать будет из входящего потока - `getInputStream()`.

Comment: я и не хочу заставить textview обрабатывать входящий поток, я лишь хочу чтобы он сам обновлялся при поступлении нового входящего сообщения, для этого нужно написать какой то класс, но у меня не получается, я на самом деле вообще трудно представляю себе как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал цикл с ожиданием `Thread.sleep(400)` и проверял, пришло ли сообщение, если сообщение `!=null`, то `publishProgress(message)` и в `onProgressUpdate` (! Точно не помню как называется метод, его нужно переопределить в AsyncTask) в ссылку на `TextView`, которую нужно заранее инициализировать, забивал текст.
Если я правильно понял суть задачи